# little issue in jquery paging code

Tags: jquery, paging

I've been working for a while to make this code works perfect.
so I did everything works good except for the paging buttons
I'm afraid that I have to post the whole code here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var pager = new Pager('comments', 3); 
        pager.init(); 
        pager.showPageNav('Pager', 'pageNavPosition'); 
        pager.showPage(3);  



function Pager(class_name, itemsPerPage) {
    this.class_name = class_name;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pages = 0;
    this.inited = false;

    this.showRecords = function(from, to) {        
        var rows = $('.' + class_name);
        // i starts from 1 to skip table header row
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i < from || i > to)  
                rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            else
                rows[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }

    this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }

        var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';

        this.currentPage = pageNumber;
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';

        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage;
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;
        this.showRecords(from, to);
    }   

    this.prev = function() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1)
            this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);
    }

    this.next = function() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {
            this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);
        }
    }                        

    this.init = function() {
        var rows = $('.' + class_name);
        var records = (rows.length); 
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
        this.inited = true;
    }

    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) {
        if (! this.inited) {
            alert("not inited");
            return;
        }
```

and my problem is here:

```
     var element = document.getElementById(positionId);

        var pagerHtml = '<span onClick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> &#171 Prev </span> | ';
        for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++)
            pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onClick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> | ';
        pagerHtml += '<span onClick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next &#187;</span>';

        element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;
    }
}
                             });
```

if you wanna look at the demo please follow the link bellow
http://jsfiddle.net/J3Qnx/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/justiceerolin/tes5N/

Creating the pager within $.ready does not create it globally, so it won't be able to reference Pager after it $.ready is complete (on clicks, etc)

Solution was to create a global pager instance, thisPager, and reference that instance instead.

The changes are the first four lines:

```
window.thisPager= new Pager('comments', 3); 
thisPager.init(); 
thisPager.showPageNav('thisPager', 'pageNavPosition'); 
thisPager.showPage(3);
```

Comment: Love you too bro.  If this solves the issue, please mark it as answered.  Thanks and best of luck!